# Deleting List Columns

Tags: list, custom-list

How can I delete One or Multiple List Columns?

Comment: I added all the list items. Now i wanna delete a few of them. Don't know how to.

Comment: May be you will not have access to delete item

Comment: Or The Article in your question is for SharePoint 2007, for 2013 https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-edit-or-delete-list-items-a4b31f53-f044-470e-9823-4526594bacde

Comment: do we even need permission to delete a list item?

Comment: Yes. Admin can remove Delete access from Permission level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a permission to can delete List columns,

> List Settings > Below Columns > click on your column that you need to
>   delete > at the bottom of page > click delete.

**Note :** the title and built-in columns can't be deleted it can only be renamed or hide.

You should have a permission to can delete Items within a list.
To delete items

- Open your list.
- Select the items that you need.
- from the above ribbon > at List tab > select delete.

If you didn't have permission to do that it will be grayed out / disabled.

Answer (score 2):

- Go to the list settings
- From the columns sections select the column you want to delete
- Here you can edit or delete the column

please check first if you have the permission or not...

Comment: Yep. Doing that. Is there any option to multi-delete?

Comment: No. you can do that using sharepoint rest api or client object model.